# EOL while scanning single-quoted string in visual studio C++

Tags: c++

So, at first while working on the code I has using a small file of about 100 words. When I think I finally managed to put some code together and get rid of all issues, I tried to put in a larger file with approximately 450,000 words.

It crashed my pc.

Now, when I try to compile the code it gives me  "`EOL while scanning single-quoted string`" and also

```
"Unexpected PDB error; FORMAT (11) 'C:\Users\....\...."
```

I am new to coding and have no idea what either of those mean, please help!

The code is supposed to read a file word by word calculate its score based on value of each letter and then put into a tuple, I then try to put the tuples into a vector and print the tuple elements to console.

Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <tuple>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

bool checkIfLowercase(string word) {

    for (int i = 0; i < word.length(); i++) {
        if (!islower(word[i])) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}

int simpleScore(string word) {
    int wordScore=0;
    for (int i = 0; i < word.length(); i++) {
        string letter(1, word[i]);

        if (letter == "a")
            wordScore = wordScore + 1;
        if (letter == "e")
            wordScore = wordScore + 1;
        if (letter == "i")
            wordScore = wordScore + 1;
        if (letter == "o")
            wordScore = wordScore + 1;
        if (letter == "u")
            wordScore = wordScore + 1;
        if (letter == "l")
            wordScore = wordScore + 1;
        if (letter == "n")
            wordScore = wordScore + 1;
        if (letter == "s")
            wordScore = wordScore + 1;
        if (letter == "t")
            wordScore = wordScore + 1;
        if (letter == "r")
            wordScore = wordScore + 1;
        if (letter == "d")
            wordScore = wordScore + 2;
        if (letter == "g")
            wordScore = wordScore + 2;
        if (letter == "b")
            wordScore = wordScore + 3;
        if (letter == "c")
            wordScore = wordScore + 3;
        if (letter == "m")
            wordScore = wordScore + 3;
        if (letter == "p")
            wordScore = wordScore + 3;
        if (letter == "f")
            wordScore = wordScore + 4;
        if (letter == "h")
            wordScore = wordScore + 4;
        if (letter == "v")
            wordScore = wordScore + 4;
        if (letter == "w")
            wordScore = wordScore + 4;
        if (letter == "y")
            wordScore = wordScore + 4;
        if (letter == "k")
            wordScore = wordScore + 5;
        if (letter == "j")
            wordScore = wordScore + 8;
        if (letter == "x")
            wordScore = wordScore + 8;
        if (letter == "q")
            wordScore = wordScore + 10;
        if (letter == "z")
            wordScore = wordScore + 10;

        else {
            wordScore = wordScore + 0;
        }

    }
    return wordScore;
}

int main()
{
    ifstream fileWithEverything("test1.txt");

    string wordFromFile;
    int amountOfWords = 0;
    int x;
    vector<tuple<string, int>> vectorWithTuples;

    while (getline(fileWithEverything, wordFromFile)) {
        if (checkIfLowercase(wordFromFile) == true) {

            amountOfWords++;

            x = simpleScore(wordFromFile);

            vectorWithTuples.push_back(make_tuple(wordFromFile, x));

        }

    }
    for (int i = 0; i < wordFromFile.length(); i++) {
        cout << get<0>(vectorWithTuples[i]) << " ";
        cout << get<1>(vectorWithTuples[i]) << endl;


        cout << "Amount of words is: " << amountOfWords << endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: Your code seems fine, at least it doesn't produce errors when trying to compile. Try doing a clean build. Build > Clean Solution, then build again. On another note, if all you're doing is comparing the first letter of the word, then do a char comparison, rather than a string comparison. Also, use `else if`, not `if` every time, or, if you use `char` instead, then use a switch statement.

Comment: Why do you create the *string* `letter` to hold just a single character? Why not compare `word[i]` directly with a character literal like `'a'`?

Comment: Also note that the `else` is only for the *last* `if`. For this I would recommend a `switch` statement instead, especially since you have multiple letters which could be combined more easily (instead of long `||` chains which would be the other choice).

Comment: When asking questions about build errors, please include the *full* and *complete* output from the build, copy-pasted as text. Also please mark out in your shown code where you get the errors, with comments on those lines. Also please take some time to read about [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).